# abelian extension of local field is unramified

Tags: local-field, ramification, unramified-extension

Why is this result true :

$K$ being a local field with algebraicaly closed residue field then an abelian extension of $K$ (let's say $L$) is totaly ramified!

I didn't find any reference in all the books or course i read.

It's exercise 7.6 p 186 in N. Childress "Class Field Theory"
This exrcise is juste after the "Decomposition theorem"
If $K$ is a local field and $L/K$ is finite galois extension then there is a totaly ramified subextension $L'$ with $L'^{ur}=L^{ur}=LK^{ur}=L'K^{ur}$  ($ur$ for "maximal unramified").

I have no idea especially after a result which assume explicitly the resifue field to be finite.